# Unable to find json in request body through Postman (nodejs/express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, wysiwyg

I am trying to send this request JSON (using Postman) to my express server but unable to find it in req.body.

```
{
    "url": "https://i.pinimg.com/236x/cf/fa/83/cffa83ebe67a00b3dfead14ce35060e9.jpg"
}
```

This is my postman request:

[image: This is my postman request img]

```
//Express Post route
router.post('/fetchbyurl',async (req,res) => {
    console.log(req.body) //undefined
})
```

My server setup:

[image: My server setup]

I am actually using this route on editorjs but couldn't since editorjs is sending JSON req in above format but I am not getting any req.body.

Comment: How is your server set up? Do you use a JSON parsing middleware?

Comment: Yes I have used used express.json() as middleware. I was also using body-parser module but then I found out that body-parser does the same thing. My other routes are working fine though

Comment: You're registering your router before the middlewares. The order is important.

Comment: thx bro Its working now. I have never encountered such issue..
thanks for taking time to answer.